# First Sync my iPad. Warn to have my iPad data deleted. Is it real?

Tags: itunes, data-synchronization, ipad

I want to sync the apps of my iPad on my iMac. iTunes warns me about the loss of the data stored on my iPad. Is this real? Can I make a backup of my iPad, Sync the Apps and then get my data back on my iPad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you authorized your iMac with the iTunes account(s) that is linked to data on the iPad? If no, do it by going to Menubar > Store > Authorize This Computer. It should allow you to sync without the data loss warning.